# Playframework2.6 + sbt + java how to work with jmx ?

Tags: java, sbt, jmx

I have a question about playframwork2.6 + sbt + java how to work with sbt. I tried two method. but failed 
Methond 1 : in build.sbt add java options

```
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true"
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9005"
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9006"
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false "
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
javaOptions += "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
javaOptions += "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
```

but 9006 and 9006 not work 
Method 2:  when use sbt run project add these parameter in the command like

```
sbt "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true" 
"-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"       "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9005"      "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9006" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" ~run
```

still not work. anyone have expecrence about this ? thank you very much

Comment: after these two method I use command  netstat -an | grep 900   have no result about 9005 and 9006

Answer (score 0):

You need to user `bin/activator` instead of `sbt` command

`bin/activator run \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9005 \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`